# WordPress little text issue

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a problem with my WordPress site. There is a little text under my footer but I don't know where it is?

[image]

Comment: Did u check it into the footer widget?

Comment: Are you using any custom plugin, also check in your templates and footer.php or simply open you project in sublime and search the text. Hopefully it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the `footer.php` file on your active theme?
You can find additional information in the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates).

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the end of the footer.php file in below path.

/wp-content/themes/traveler/